# Groovy : add root closure if condition

Tags: groovy, closures

A little bit confuse about this simple use case :
I want to add a closure around an other one only with conditions.
For the moment, I only succeed to do this :

```
if(condition) {
  my_root_closure {
    my_main_closure {
      do_stuff()
    }
  }
} else {
  my_main_closure {
    do_stuff()
  }
}
```

I would like to do this without repeat the my_main_closure bloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repetition, you could create new closure that calls `my_main_closure` and store it in a variable:

```
def mmc = {
    my_main_closure {
        do_stuff()
    }
}

if(condition) {
    my_root_closure( mmc )
} else {
    mmc()
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something more different :  

`def root = {}
if (condition) { root = my_root_closure }
root {
  my_main_closure {
    do_stuff()
  }
}`

Comment: @C3PO This could also work, but it should be `def root = { it() }`, otherwise closure would do nothing when `condition == false`.

Comment: And it was my problem :)
I will test this.
Thks